# How to automatically close mobile menu on scroll in website

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm looking to implement a feature on my website, www.boatsnbeds.com, where the mobile menu automatically closes when users scroll the page. This is to enhance user experience by ensuring that the menu doesn't obstruct content as users navigate through the site on their mobile devices.

I've searched for solutions but haven't found a straightforward way to achieve this functionality. I believe it may require some custom JavaScript or CSS modifications, but I'm not sure where to start.

Here's what I'm aiming to accomplish:

When users open the mobile menu by tapping on the menu icon,
Then, when users start scrolling the page, I want the mobile menu to automatically close without requiring them to manually close it.
I'm reaching out to seek advice or guidance on how to implement this feature effectively. Any insights, code snippets, or resources would be highly appreciated.

Here's what I've already tried:

Reviewed the JavaScript responsible for toggling the mobile menu.
Checked for any CSS rules that might be affecting the menu behavior.
Tested on different mobile devices and browsers to ensure it's not device-specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)